# Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, gradle, build.gradle

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+
```

and this is my build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
    compile files('libs/aspose-cells-8.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov-jdk15-146.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-library-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/renderscript-v8.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
 }
```

[Gradle Build Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afJ0w.png)

[Project Structure - Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwntF.png)

Please I need Your Help

Comment: try this `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'`

Comment: Could Not resolve com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1

Comment: It should work (Make sure you have active Internet connection & no firewall is blocking android studio) OR you can also add bolts JAR directly like parse. see this: https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

Comment: Also check your `gradle.properties` if it contains any proxy. also check android studio global proxy setting if it is blocking android studio.

Comment: Are you working with offline mode in gradle?

Comment: No , I don't use offline mode

Answer (score 0):

Go app->libs then select parse.1+.jar right click on it and then select "As a library"

Answer (score 0):

You just have to Update your Android Studio.
"Check For Updates..."
Already

Answer (score 0):

Include the following dependencies to your Gradle
 `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
And Select File->Invalidate Caches and Restart and select Invalidate Caches and Restart.
Wait a few minutes and Android Studio should restart and everything will be in sync.
**Anyway Parse has been expired!!!**

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Use this code for import the bolts library place it  in  `buildscript` tag in `build.gradle` file.